# how long to leave the sliced onion mixed with salt/pepper for onion Bhaji/onion fritters/onion pakoras?

Tags: indian-cuisine, onions

How long should we leave the sliced onion mixed with salt and red chillies/green chillies, for them to be used for onion fritters/onion bhaji/onion Pakoras with gram flour? 
Suggested time is usually 15-20min.

What if it is increased or decreased? How does it affect the taste of the pakora?
Accordingly, what should be the quantity of rice flour to add to the crispiness of pakora?

Answer (score 3):

There are more than one methods and answers to above question. As per the Mumbai Special Ghati Bhajiya, Sliced Onions must be mixed with Salt for at least 15 Minutes & Maximum for 1/2 Hour. The water content must than be drained keeping only dry salted onions. Then Gram flour & other Spices should be added to Onions, just to bind, so Bhajiyas or Pakoras can be made.
Taste of Onion in Bhajiyas or Pakoras turns slightly mild, yet crispy, because due to low water content onion cook fast without turning dark!

Rice Flour, it can also be added or can be a substitute of gram flour for crispy Bhajiyas. Rice flour should be coarse and not fine.
For Crispness Ratio of Rice Flour to Gram Flour should be 1:1 or Rice Flour should totally substitute Gram Flour.

Comment: But I was informed to use the same water content which the onions sheds and use it to mix with the flour, and add following    
    1 table spoon of yogurt
    1 table spoon of oil
if these are insufficient to make the batter wet, then add upto a glass of water(this can be varied, depending on how thick the batter forms)...

Comment: I have already mentioned that there are more than one method of making Pakoras, from my personal experience I infer that more the water content the less crisp are Pakoras. Also with more water content, the use of Oil & Cooking time also increases. All this affects the fresh taste of Pakoras.

Comment: hmmm.. thanks for the suggestions.. Will try to experiment with different % of water/oil/dryness.

Comment: I second that @VikramS.Parikh . I too avoid any extra water in onion pakoras. Mostly because they become soggy. If you decide to use the water released by onions than that should do, no need for any extra water to be added after that.